# OS X El Capitan downloading froze and now it won't let me download?

Tags: macos, upgrade, mac-appstore

I was trying to upgrade to OS X El Capitan when my screensaver kicked in or something and froze the download. But now the App Store shows it "download" as apposed to "downloading" when I try and download it. And nothing happens vs before when the screen turned into an iPad screen. Not sure if there is a file to delete of what?
[image]

Comment: Actually, this is different, and I am having the same problem.  :(